# MYSQL - Set data into one column rather then two

Tags: mysql

Here is a mysql query that results two rows
As you can see the second row is coming from this sub query in below query

```
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS cped ON cped.row_id = simple.entity_id
    AND `attribute_id` IN (SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute`
    WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price','special_price')) AND cped.store_id IN (13,0)
```

**The row has price = price & other has special_price = price, i want them into single row
is that possible ?**

```
SELECT parent.entity_id AS parent_id,
    simple.entity_id AS simple_id,
    simple.sku AS simple_sku,
    cpp.rule_price AS rule_price,
    cped.value AS price,
    cpev.value AS simple_name,
    parent.type_id AS type_id,
    wi.store_id AS wishlist_store_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS parent
JOIN catalog_product_super_link AS link ON parent.row_id = link.parent_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity AS simple ON link.product_id = simple.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalogrule_product_price AS cpp ON cpp.product_id = simple.entity_id AND
    cpp.website_id = (SELECT `website_id` FROM `store` WHERE `store_id` = '13')
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS cped ON cped.row_id = simple.entity_id
    AND `attribute_id` IN (
        SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute`
        WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('price','special_price')) 
    AND cped.store_id IN (13,0)
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev ON cpev.row_id = simple.entity_id
    AND cpev.store_id IN (13,0) AND cpev.attribute_id = (
        SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute`
        WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('name') 
        order by `attribute_id` DESC 
        LIMIT 1)
LEFT JOIN wishlist_item AS wi ON parent.row_id = wi.product_id AND `wishlist_id` = '1'
WHERE parent.entity_id = '9244' 
order by cped.store_id DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried LIMIT 1 at the end of the query but then it does not return 'special price' in row

Comment: basically i want special_price & price values in single row

Comment: I would be very tempted to start again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but what does that mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *pivot*, so use the usual idiom for pivoting in MySQL: aggregate a conditional with each value.

```
SELECT parent.entity_id AS parent_id,
    simple.entity_id AS simple_id,
    simple.sku AS simple_sku,
    cpp.rule_price AS rule_price,
    MAX(IF(cped.attribute_code = 'price', cped.value, NULL)) AS price,
    MAX(IF(cped.attribute_code = 'special_price', cped.value, NULL)) AS special_price,
    cpev.value AS simple_name,
    parent.type_id AS type_id,
    wi.store_id AS wishlist_store_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS parent
JOIN catalog_product_super_link AS link ON parent.row_id = link.parent_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity AS simple ON link.product_id = simple.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalogrule_product_price AS cpp ON cpp.product_id = simple.entity_id AND
    cpp.website_id = (SELECT `website_id` FROM `store` WHERE `store_id` = '13')
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cped.store_id, cped.row_id, cped.value, ea.attribute_code
           FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal AS cped
           JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ea.attribute_id = cped.attribute_id
           WHERE ea.attribute_code IN ('price','special_price')
           AND cped.store_id IN (13,0)) AS cped ON cped.row_id = simple.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev ON cpev.row_id = simple.entity_id
    AND cpev.store_id IN (13,0) AND cpev.attribute_id = (
        SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute`
        WHERE `attribute_code` IN ('name') 
        order by `attribute_id` DESC 
        LIMIT 1)
LEFT JOIN wishlist_item AS wi ON parent.row_id = wi.product_id AND `wishlist_id` = '1'
WHERE parent.entity_id = '9244' 
GROUP BY parent_id, simple_id, simple_sku, rule_price, simple_name, type_id, wishlist_store_id
ORDER BY cped.store_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Error in query (1055): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'local_dollskill.simple.entity_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Very thanks for the answer but it shows this error on executing

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: Yes checking on it

Comment: not getting exactly, not sure how it helps.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You have to add all the other columns to the `GROUP BY` list.

Comment: That works but returns 4 rows, i am adding LIMIT 1 as i need only one valid record.
is won't cause any issue right sir ?

Comment: Why don't you just select the store ID that you want in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235093/discussion-between-newtophp-and-barmar).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68527699/update-sql-query-add-order-by